# Django many to many performance issue

Tags: django, performance

I've profiled a piece of code that processes an excel spreadsheet of 350 rows and is about 200 lines long.  75.5% of the time is spent on this many to many call:

```
332       388    117059833 301700.6     75.5                      if obj.wave not in c.waves.all():
```

and here is most of the rest:

```
136        97       341749   3523.2      0.2                      q.waves.add(obj.wave)
137        97     30551176 314960.6     19.7                      q.save()
```

wave is a model, 
obj has a foreign key field to wave

```
wave = models.ForeignKey(Wave)
```

and q has a many to many field to wave

```
waves = models.ManyToManyField(Wave)
```

I've checked the many to many table and there is a key on every field.  I've changed it from ISAM to Innodb with no difference.

Is there anything I can do to improve performance - it's currently taking 20 secs per line and using all the CPU on a 2 core linux box - before I rewrite the code to get rid of the many to many structure?

Comment: We need more context for those lines. Are they being called repeatedly on the same instances? How are those instances retrieved in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operation can be costly specially if there are so many `waves` record, you can simplify your query as:

`if not c.waves.filter(id__exact=obj.wave.id).exists():
    pass # do something`

Comment: Yes very expensive!! Now down to 2%        853777 instead of 117059833. Many thanks.